# Slick Slider AutoPlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Estou montando uma Slick Slider com 4 imagens, porém, ele carrega todas imagens em tela e não faz o Slick autoplay sozinho.

JS:

```
$('.single-item').slick({
slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  responsive: 
  [
  {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
          infinite: true,
          arrows: true,
          slidesToShow: 2
      }
  },
  {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
          infinite: true,
          arrows: true,
          slidesToShow: 1
      }
  }
  ]
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="single-item logos col-12">

 <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/bradesco.png" alt="">
 </div>


 <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/ole.png" alt="">
 </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/pan.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/banrisul.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/itau.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/safra.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/votorantim.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/images/site/bic.png" alt="">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.logos{
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap
}

.logos .logo{
height: 150px;
background-size: cover !important
}

.logos .logo img {
height: 100px;
width: 150px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você está iniciando o plugin antes de carregar o HTML do slider. Com isso o plugin não acha a div `.single-item` e todas as imagens do slider são exibidas na tela.

É preciso verificar a ordem em que as coisas são carregadas. Se este for o caso, você pode inserir o código que inicializa o plugin dentro do evento `.ready`, onde a inicialização do plugin só irá ser executada após o carregamento do DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // inicie o plugin aqui!

});
```

Veja como funciona:

```css
.logos{
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap
}

.logos .logo{
height: 150px;
background-size: cover !important
}

.logos .logo img {
height: 100px;
width: 150px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.single-item').slick({
   slidesToShow: 4,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
   responsive: 
   [
   {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
          infinite: true,
          arrows: true,
          slidesToShow: 2
      }
   },
   {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
          infinite: true,
          arrows: true,
          slidesToShow: 1
      }
   }
   ]
   });
});
</script>
<div class="single-item logos col-12">

 <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
 </div>


 <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
 </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  </div>
```

A ordem de carregamento das bibliotecas/HTML:

- jQuery
- Plugin
- HTML
- Script que inicia o plugin

Se for usar o `.ready`, pode ser:

- jQuery
- Script que inicia o plugin (dentro do `.ready`)
- Plugin
- HTML

Ou:

- jQuery
- Plugin
- Script que inicia o plugin (dentro do `.ready`)
- HTML

Ou até:

- jQuery
- Script que inicia o plugin (dentro do `.ready`)
- HTML
- Plugin

Ou também:

- jQuery
- HTML
- Plugin
- Script que inicia o plugin

Veja que o jQuery sempre vem em primeiro lugar.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, faltou chamar o plugin no carregamento inicial do DOM, agradeço mesmo!